# WP MU - Accessing 'Domain-Mapped' WP-Admin with a subdomain

Tags: multisite, subdomains, domain-mapping

After mapping the domains to each WP MU blog I'm having to separately login to each of the blogs and from what I've read online it's not possible or not secure to keep a user logged in on different domains if you're using cookies.

Is it possible to still have each WP blog mapped (wpmu1.hubdomain.com => www.newdomain.com), however be able to access the WP-Admin through the subdomain version of the WP blog? I'm guessing that if the WP-Admin is still under the same domain I can enable cookies to cross each subdomain?

Answer (score 0):

Despite the fact that the plugin recommendations are off-topic here, I don't know any other way how to do what you want to do without using a plugin.

I have experience with [Domain Mapping](http://premium.wpmudev.org/project/domain-mapping/) plugin from WPMUDEV. This plugin allows you to use mapped domains for the front end and original subdomains for admin dashboard.

However this plugin is not free, but it can do what you need. Maybe there is another plugin what can do what you want, but I don't know any.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the plugin [WordPress MU Domain Mapping](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/), it's a matter of enabling the following option:

[image]

If you want to do this on a per site basis, you'd have to manipulate the function [`dm_redirect_admin`](http://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/tags/0.5.4.3/domain_mapping.php#L607). Something like:

```
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', function()
{
    remove_action( 'admin_init', 'dm_redirect_admin' );
    add_action( 'admin_init', 'my_redirect_admin' );
});
```